# Is there a way to use variable to index a list in a list in python?

Tags: python

So I've been writing a larger project and i put lists in a list and i used a loop to index multiple
lists in less code but now I'm getting errors.

Does anyone have any answers that maintains the less lines of code.

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]

list2 = [1,2,3]

list_of_lists = [list1,list2]

for x in range(0,2):
    print(list_of_lists[x[0]])
    print(list_of_lists[x[1]])
    print(list_of_lists[x[2]])
```

Comment: `for x in list_of_lists` will give you `x` as one of the lists.

Comment: `list_of_lists[x]` would be one of your individual lists.  `list_of_lists[x][0]` would therefore be the first element of that individual list.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you want the code to do. "I'm getting errors" is not helpful. Please make sure you understand how `for` loops work in Python.

Comment: The point of writing a loop is that you *don't* copy-paste the same line of code multiple times.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm pretty sure OP understands that, and has two questions: 1) how to resolve the errors? 2) how to avoid the copy-paste and make use of loops properly?

Answer (score 1):

This code prints the two lists that were combined in `list_of_lists`

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]

list2 = [1,2,3]

list_of_lists = [list1,list2]

for x in range(0,2):
    print(list_of_lists[x])
```

If you want it even shorter:

```
list_of_lists = [["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, I would be curious as to the use you are trying to get out of this. In any case I think you have the wrong idea fundamentally about how to access elements in a multidimensional list. In general, for a two dimensional list an element is given by

```
example[x][y]
```

Where x specifies which list in your list of lists you are trying to access, and y specifies the element in that list. For example:

```
letters = [a, b, c]
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
combined = [letters, numbers]
```

`combined[0] = [a, b, c]`

`combined[1] = [1, 2, 3]`

`combined[0][0] = a`

`combined[1][1] = 2`

now, if you wanted to loop over the individual lists, you can do something like

```
for x in combined:
      print(x)
```

will print your lists in whole (list1 will be printed then list2). If on the other hand you wanted to list each element individually, you need to write a nested loop. You could do so like this.

```
for x in combined:
      for element in x:
            print(element)
```

This would individually print each item in your list of lists. Take some time to understand how loops/iterations/generators work in python. Avoid using indexes like you have in your code unless absolutely necessary. Let python do that work for you.

Comment: Please don't suggest the use of `list` (or other built-in names) as a variable name - that's going to cause utter confusion when they actually try to use the built-in later.

Comment: Good point, edited to reflect it, thanks.